# Buying and selling things with debit/credit cards

Tags: sunni

Assalamu alaykum! Sorry if there are mistakes, English is not my native!
For two months I have been continuously trying to find fatwas on the Internet about whether it is permissible to sell goods online. The problem is that if you are a seller, in 90% of cases you will be paid with credit cards. As far as I understood, credit cards are strictly prohibited, even if paid before the interest is added. Also, all sheikhs forbided to take coupons, since this is also riba (I’m here talking about non-islamic banks). The problem is that when a customer makes a purchase with a credit card, the seller sends 1-3% of the commission to the bank, which serves the customer. That is, the buyer gives his money from the bank and comission is returned back to the same bank. These commissions (about 50% from 1-3%) always then goes for creating coupons for the customers. Thus, it turns out that the merchants help banks with creating riba coupons. And the question is, what should I do? Scholars didn’t prohibit to buy cars and fly on airplanes, even though we pay for insurance, cause of it’s ubiquitousness and inevitability. Still, I have doubts, cause I’ve couldn’t found any evidences. There are fatwas where it is allowed to accept credit cards, and they referred to the fact, that there is no difference for the seller with which money do customers buy their products. But no one of them didn’t take into account that very commission which sellers send to the issuing banks to create coupons. I’m in desperate. It is clearly a riba, but at the same time there is no other choice. I’ve just wanted to open an online store and for two months I’m just non-stop searching for non-existent fatwas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert your credit card to debit card. Cause I think you don't need to pay interest(Riba) for debit card. And a credit card can be used from Islamic bank where there is no interest(Riba). And I highly recommend to watch this video for more info about this

https://youtu.be/Q5_kZbFk4p0

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know that debit cards are quite permissible, but the problem is that I’m a merchant, so customers will pay me with credit cards, not debit cards. Comissions from these credit cards are then transfered to the banks in a way of a coupons and all scholars told that coupons are riba.

Comment: How about use credit card from Islamic bank

Comment: Even if I lived in a country with islamic banks, it would not solve this problem, cause my customers even if had an islam credit card, would buy my products with mostly non-Islamic credit cards

Comment: @FatimaSaleh I actually don't know much about this. But i found a article from islamqa.info. check this out. 

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/102744/selling-goods-to-someone-who-pays-with-a-credit-card-and-giving-a-commission-to-the-bank-which-is-added-to-the-price-of-the-goods